# monitor and update variable number of fields in php form

Tags: php, sql

I have an inventory form that pulls a variable number of rows of items from a database and creates a table/list of them, with input text boxes for quantity of cases( of 12) and individual items, and the script updates the total box with the sum of those two.  I have it working if I put discrete sections of code in for each row, and have tried many while/for loops and the problem I think is the function is inside the loop and stops it from working. I looked at posts using .each() , but do not see any example that works with my setup.  I went and answered a couple simple questions on here for others before posting this question, hoping to please the code gods ;-)

```
<form>
      <div class="ex3">
        <div class="headrow">
          <div class="column">Batch</div>
          <div class="column">Name</div>
          <div class="column">UPC</div>
          <div class="column">Cases</div>
          <div class="column">Bottles</div>
          <div class="column">Counted</div>
        </div>
<?php 
        // grab all the pertinant entries from the database and create a row of entries for each one
    $sql="SELECT BatchNum, BatchName, UPC FROM Batches WHERE CurrentBatch=1 AND UPC <> '' ORDER by BatchNum DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row_cnt = 0;  
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div class=row>';
        echo '<div class=column>'.$row['BatchNum'].'</div>';
        echo '<div class=column>'.$row['BatchName'].'</div>';
        echo '<div class=column>'.$row['UPC'].'</div>';
        echo '<div class=column> <label for="CaseCount"></label><input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="^\d{1,3}$" size="4" class="form-control" id="CaseCount'.$row_cnt.'" name="CaseCount'.$row_cnt.'" value="" ></div>';
        echo '<div class=column> <label for="BottleCount"></label><input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="^\d{1,3}$" size="4" class="form-control" id="BottleCount'.$row_cnt.'" name="BottleCount'.$row_cnt.'" value=""></div>';
        echo '<div class=column> <label for="Counted"></label><input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="^\d{1,8}$" size="8" class="form-control" id="Counted'.$row_cnt.'" name="Counted'.$row_cnt.'" value="" required></div>';
        $row_cnt += 1;
        echo "</div>";
        }
      }
?>        
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</form>        

 <script>
    // monitor the case and bottle count fields and update the counted field.
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#CaseCount0, #BottleCount0').on('input', function() { 
        var Counted0 = 0;
        var value1 = $('#CaseCount0').val();
        var value2 = $('#BottleCount0').val();
        var Counted0 = (value1 * 12) + (value2 * 1);
        $('#Counted0').val(Counted0);
        });
      $('#CaseCount1, #BottleCount1').on('input', function() { 
        var Counted1 = 0;
        var value1 = $('#CaseCount1').val();
        var value2 = $('#BottleCount1').val();
        var Counted1 = (value1 * 12) + (value2 * 1);
        $('#Counted1').val(Counted1);
        });
      $('#CaseCount2, #BottleCount2').on('input', function() { 
        var Counted2 = 0;
        var value1 = $('#CaseCount2').val();
        var value2 = $('#BottleCount2').val();
        var Counted2 = (value1 * 12) + (value2 * 1);
        $('#Counted2').val(Counted2);
        });
        //  might be 20-30 of these lines
    });

</script>
```

here is a script section I have tried, but could not get to work, I do not think it is good practice for the function to be inside the loop:

```
   var numrows = <?php echo $numrows ?>-1;
   var i;   
   $(document).ready(function() {
     for(var i = 0; i <= numrows; i++) {
       $("#CaseCount"+i).on('input', function() { 
         this["Counted"+i] = 0;
         var value1 = $("#CaseCount" + i).val();
         var value2 = $("#BottleCount" + i).val();
         $("#Counted"+i).val((value1 * 12)+(value2 * 1));
       });
     }
   });
```

Comment: could you make your question a bit more clear please

Comment: sure... I want to replace the 3 .on(input) sections with a loop or similar to do 'num_rows' iterations. I have tried a few variations of the loop, but having that function inside the loop is bad form.